# Vuex TypeScript does not update String, but Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am currently "working" with vue. The store is updating my array, but does not update my string or boolean.

My code ist [here](https://github.com/auryn31/sse-vertx/tree/master/reactive-vue):

i commit my string every second and the string does not show up at the frontend (vuex dev tools show the state is correct, my console log does not)

My Store looks like this:

```
const state: State = {
  cars: [],
  date: "false",
  carsCounter: 0,
};
```

my export:

```
const getters = {
  getCars(state: State) {
    return state.cars;
  },
  getDate(state: State) {
    return state.date;
  },
  getCarsCounter(state: State) {
    return state.carsCounter;
  }
};

const { read, commit, dispatch } = getStoreAccessors<State, State>("");

export const readCarsFromSse = read(getters.getCars);
export const readDate = read(getters.getDate);
export const readCarsCounter = read(getters.getCarsCounter);
```

and I use it in the date component like this:

```
export default class DateVue extends Vue {
  date = readDate(store);
  cars = readCarsFromSse(store);
  testString = readCarsCounter(store);

  mounted() {
    Timeloader.loadTime();
  }

}
```

did anyone know why the strings are not updated but the array is?

thanks

Comment: What's `read` function?

Comment: ah sorry: `const { read, commit, dispatch } = getStoreAccessors<State, State>("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> did anyone know why the strings are not updated but the array is?

In the view, you use affectation once to get values from your Vuex state. When you get an array, Vuex returns the observer of the array, and the item values will be kept up-to-date. But primitive values are just primitive values.

Here is a solution, using [vuex-class](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class):

Install `vuex-class`:

```
npm install vuex-class
```

Then:

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Getter } from "vuex-class";

@Component
export default class DateVue extends Vue {
  @Getter("getDate")
  date!: string;
  @Getter("getCars")
  cars!: any[];
  @Getter("getCarsCounter")
  testString!: number;

  mounted() {
    Timeloader.loadTime();
  }
}
```

… Or without *vuex-class* (solution provided by auryn31):

```
export default class DateVue extends Vue {
  get date() { return readDate(store); }
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: but I must be possible to use primitive values in vuex, they use it in there docu as well 

Comment: @auryn31 Which documentation?

Comment: @auryn31 In this documentation, you'll find several examples on how to use a value from a Vuex store. You can do: `computed: { count () { return this.$store.state.count } }` or use the `mapState` Helper.

Comment: thanks, I worked it out by using an object instead of an primitive value

Comment: ok, the answer was to use get :-D `get date() {
    return readDate(store);
  } `